# Finding Elvis ?:

Tags: regex

I have been tasked to find Elvis (using eclipse search). Is there any regex that I can use to find him?

The "Elvis Operator" (`?:`) is a shortening of Java's ternary operator.

I have tried `\?[\s\S]*[:]` but it doesn't match multiline.
Is there such a refactoring where I could change Elvis into an if-else block?

Comment: Is this in Groovy? If so, it would really help if you'd say so. (It's really the conditional operator in Java, btw - "ternary" just describes how many operands it has. It's *a* ternary operator, and currently the only one, but its name is the conditional operator.)

Comment: Jon Skeet is Elvis.

Comment: Looking at the Groovy reference, it calls the binary operator 'value :? value' the Elvis operator, and the ternary operator 'boolean ? value : value' a "traditional ternary operator".

Are you talking about the Elvis operator, or a conditional operator? If it is the Elvis operator, you can just search for "?:"

Comment: In what language are you looking for that operator?

Comment: oops, my bad, I meant the traditional ternary operator.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**
Sorry, I had posted a regex for the ternary operator, if your problem is multiline you could use this:

```
\?(\p{Z}|\r\n|\n)*:
```

Comment: String hello = "I'm not an 'elvis operator'? Are you: sure, unsure";

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to explicitly match line delimiters if you want to match across multiple lines.  \R will match any of them(platform-independent), in Eclipse 3.4 anyway, or you can use the proper one for your file (\r, \n, \r\n).  E.g. `\?.*\R*.*:` will work if there's only one line break. You can't use \R in a character class, though, so if you don't know how many lines the operator might span, you'd have to construct a character class with your line delimiter and any character that might appear in an operand.  Something like `([-\r\n\w\s\[\](){}=!/%*+&^|."']*)\?([-\r\n\w\s\[\](){}=!/%*+&^|."']*):([-\r\n\w\s\[\](){}=!/%*+&^|."']*)`.  I've included parentheses to capture the operands as groups so you could find and replace.

You've got a pretty big problem, though, if this is Java (and probably any other language).  The ternary conditional ?: operator creates an expression, while an if statement is not an expression.  Consider:

```
boolean even = true;
int foo = even ? 2 : 3;
int bar = if (even) 2 else 3;
```

The third line is syntactically incorrect; the two conditional constructs are not equivalent.  (What you'd actually get from the second line if you used my regex to find and replace is `if (int foo = even) 2 else 3;` which has additional problems.)

So, you can find the ?: operators with the regex above (or something similar; I may have missed some characters you need to include in the class), but you won't necessarily be able to replace them with 'if' statements.

Comment: `int foo = even ? 2 : 3;` would need to be refactored to something like `if (even) { int foo = 2; } else { int foo = 3; };` in most C-like languages.

Comment: @Swante The scope of foo would be wrong i guess. You won't be able to use it outside the if/else